# All records of given month and one previous record if exists SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a user role change summary report for given month of the year into Excel.

User input: April-2023

There are two tables involved.
Table: ROLE

```
ROLE_ID | ROLE_NAME
1       | Role 1
2       | Role 2
3       | Role 3
```

Table: USER_AUDIT

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | ROLE_ID | CREATED_AT | UPDATED_AT | AUDIT_ACTION | AUDIT_DATE
1       | User 1    | 1       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Created      | '01-01-23'         
1       | User 1    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '01-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
1       | User 1    | 3       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '02-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
2       | User 2    | 1       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Created      | '01-01-23'         
2       | User 2    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '01-02-23'
2       | User 2    | 3       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '01-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
2       | User 2    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '02-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
3       | User 3    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Created      | '01-03-23' 
4       | User 4    | 3       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Created      | '01-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
```

In above table only user 1, 2, and 4 had some change in April-2023.

Report (Excel): Changes for April-2023

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | ACTIVITY                                      | CHANGED_AT
1       | User 1    | Updated role from Role 1 to Role 2 to Role 3  | <last-audit-date>
2       | User 2    | Updated role from Role 2 to Role 3 to Role 2  | <last-audit-date>
4       | User 4    | Created with role Role 3                      | <last-audit-date>
```

I can process for activity statement for report in `Java` but cannot read the whole USER_AUDIT table as it can be big.

How to get record of given month (April-23 in above case) and one previous record of each user if exists just to keep in the record indicating the role change is made from which existing role?

Need to read from USER_AUDIT as:

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | ROLE_ID | CREATED_AT | UPDATED_AT | AUDIT_ACTION | AUDIT_DATE
1       | User 1    | 1       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Created      | '01-01-23' //One previous record of user 1
1       | User 1    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '01-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
1       | User 1    | 3       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '02-04-23' //Changed in April-2023     
2       | User 2    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '01-02-23' //One previous record of user 2
2       | User 2    | 3       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '01-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
2       | User 2    | 2       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Updated      | '02-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
4       | User 4    | 3       | <datetime> | <datetime> | Created      | '01-04-23' //Changed in April-2023
```

I can get the record of given month but not sure how to get one more previous record of each user if exists.

```
select r.ROLE_NAME, ua.* 
FROM USER_AUDIT ua JOIN ROLE r ON ua.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID 
WHERE AUDIT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2023/04/01 0:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND TO_DATE('2023/04/30 23:59:59', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 
ORDER BY ua.USER_ID asc, ua.AUDIT_DATE asc;
```

Open for different approach as well

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the previous month?  What code did attempt, can you show it?

Comment: If I read only for given month, for the activity statement in the report 'Updated role from Role 1 to Role 2 to Role 3', cannot know ' from Role 1' as in the selected record I'll have record of 'to Role 2' and 'to Role 3'

Comment: I'd still rather see the code than try to guess at what you are saying.  Please show us the "previous" code, and explain what isn't working in its output.

Comment: Did you try LAG analytic function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function to find the next value and ensure that either the next value is after the start of the month or the current value is before the month's end.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select r.ROLE_NAME,
         ua.*,
         LEAD(audit_date) OVER (ORDER BY audit_date) AS next_audit_date 
  FROM   USER_AUDIT ua
         JOIN ROLE r
         ON ua.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID 
)
WHERE  COALESCE(NEXT_AUDIT_DATE, AUDIT_DATE) >= DATE '2023-04-01'
AND    AUDIT_DATE <  DATE '2023-05-01'
ORDER BY
       ua.USER_ID asc,
       ua.AUDIT_DATE asc;
```